# What is the performance of INSERT with JOIN versus using INSERT with CASE?

Tags: sql, performance, join, case

Of course this is not much of a factor for most small transactions, but with larger data sets, assuming there are useful indexes in place, is it faster to do an INSERT using a JOIN instead of using CASE?

**Example using CASE** (in T-SQL):

```
INSERT into Foo
(CarID, CarMake)
(SELECT CarID,
   CASE WHEN CarModel = 'Odyssey' THEN 'Honda'
        WHEN CarModel = 'Sienna' THEN 'Toyota' END
        as CarMake
    FROM FooCar)
```

**Example using JOIN:**

```
INSERT into Foo
(CarID, CarMakeID)
(SELECT A.CarID, B.CarMake
 FROM FooCar as A
 JOIN FooMake as B on (A.CarModel = B.CarModel)
 )
```

Which of those two statements would meet the objective of more speed? Please look past the example data sample which does not represent the problem very well in terms of magnitude. 
I can't find another question like this, but it seems like something that should be asked and answered already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `case` statement would, in general, be faster.  The `join` is better in most other respects.  The purpose of having reference tables is to avoid having to hard-code specific values in the code.  It is better to use the reference table.

The performance difference would generally be very small, especially if `FooMake` is well designed and has an index on `CarModel`.  You should not be looking for such micro-optimizations on queries.  Strive first to get the query to work correctly, using reasonable SQL, and then move toward performance.

The two versions are only equivalent if all makes are present in and appear exactly once in `FooMake`.

Comment: My example did not state this, but my intent was that FooMake was normalized, having only one record per make. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hard coded query values (like those string literals in your CASE statement) will get translated into in-memory machine language commands and will always be faster than the disk I/O required to perform the join.

The reason you have the table instead of CASE statements is maintainability not speed. What if you have the CASE statement act on two fields instead of one? Or add some branching logic? Hard-coding your queries for speed is like  racing across the frozen tundra on a snowmobile which flips over, trapping you underneath. At night, the ice-weasels come.